# How can I keep the string of one space only and replace all the other spaces using sed?

Tags: regex, sed, replace

- I have a data file (1.data) which contains the following:

  ```
            USSR                  8649                 BS275                  Asia
         Cananda                  3852                  BS25         North America
  ```

  **What I want is to keep the string of only one space and replace all the other spaces with :**

My sed code:

```
sed 's/ *   */:/g' 1.data

:USSR:8649:BS275:Asia
:Cananda:3852:BS25:North America
```

That works perfect.

Since I know A+ matches A, AA, AAA, AAAA and so on, I tried another regular expression.

```
sed 's/ *  +/:/g' 1.data



          USSR                  8649                 BS275                  Asia
       Cananda                  3852                  BS25         North America
```

However, it does not work. Nothing changes.

What mistake did I make?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Added. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 2):

Add option `-E` (switch from regular expressions to extended regular expressions) or replace `+` with `\+`.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` would treat "+" as a normal character if no `-r` option is added. And "+" meta-character would match to one or more after `-r: extended regular expressions` is added. So your command can be modified as,

```
sed -r 's/[[:space:]]+/:/g' 1.data
```